# The proper word to denote the end of a count-off in the line in a PE class

Tags: word-choice, british-english, speech

‎What does the last student in the line say( in a PE class at school) when the class has lined up and counted off?

At the beginning of a PE class, the teacher always asks students to line up in one row. Then he wants to know exactly how many students there are. So he tells the students to count off. So the countdown begins (1st, 2nd, 3nd,...26th) and continues untill it reaches the last student in the line. Then he or she tells her number in the line( for example, 26) and must say:"26th", which is supposed to inevitably be followed by other phrase indicating that that student is the last in the line, so the count down has ended. Declaring this, the student usually leaves the line by making one step forward and reports to the teacher that all the students have counted off.

The wording of such an answer doesn't change from class to class at all, so it's more of a cliché. In my native language we say "The count is over." And I'm interested to know its English equivalents. Is it "The count is off/ over" or something else? I'm aware of the fact that there might me different variants depending on the version of English, so I would narrow it down to British English usage, since it's the version I'm most interested in.

Comment: Is this  a military PE class? I would guess that the last student is supposed to say "The count is [42]."

Comment: Educational terms and food terms are very very local, so listen to what the locals say and talk like they do.

Comment: If the last number called is "42," isn't that enough? I hope it's not a math class.

Comment: @JohnLawler A 'no answer' answer is very legitimate. Not having an existing word/phrase does not make a question off-topic or opinion-based. Please do not vote to close questions that you think don't have an answer or may only have an answer for a very small set of speakers. There may well be an answer that you don't know of -or- you claim that there is no such word is a good answer. (I would upvote your answer of 'there doesn't exist such a word'.)

Comment: @Mitch I thought a voter's reason for closing was not a matter of SE policy. Has that changed? I've given a no answer answer dozens of times and it never matters and it seems to do no good for anybody. This question **is** opinion-based -- it's based on the opinion that everybody uses the same specialized dialect for specialized educational activities all over the world. Why are you trying to apparently drum up useless answers? Is this an economic matter, or just political?

Comment: @JohnLawler No need to turn away perfectly good questions out of lack of knowledge. It's not asking for your opinion on if you think the counting is good or fun. It's just about the word if one exists. There might be a dialect or subculture  (eg military has been mentioned) where this might be done in English. If you don't know the word then let others try to answer. If you know from lots of experience that the word is likely to not exist, then answer with that. Open the door to show limits of our knowledge rather than shut down out of spite.

Comment: @Mitch: I wouldn't say it's a "perfectly good question".  Quite the contrary. That's why I voted to close it. Before i wrote the comments above.

Answer (score 7):

**No such thing.**

The question is based on a misapprehension about similarity between two cultures. In this case there is none.

(And I suffered PE at an English Grammar School, in the days when such a thing would have existed if it had ever existed. No teacher counted schoolchildren in a line in the way described, so the question of what the last one would say does not arise.)

Comment: Agree completely.

Comment: To clarify for the OP, this is saying there is no such practice, in any English speaking cultures that we are aware of, when counting off a line of people, for the last person to say or do something special. So there is no such phrase corresponding to the one in the OP's culture/language.

Comment: @Mitch — You are right to point out the limitations of my short response. Shooting from the hip, rather. I‘ll use your comment to expand and improve my answer, if I may.

Comment: Sure, go ahead.